# Do Django delete db_index?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am using postgresql for my django app.
Managed to delete almost 500000 rows, but size of my DB didn't lower significantly.
Deleted them with smth like `lots.objects.filter(id__in=[ids]).delete()` in chunks (because it's too hard to delete so many rows in one query).

Some columns have `db_index=True`, so I think indexes were not deleted.
Do I have the possibility to delete also indexes for deleted objects from django?
Maybe there is also a way to see unused indexes from Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of this has anything to do with Django. If an item is deleted from a database, it is always automatically deleted from any indexes - otherwise indexing just wouldn't work.

Normally you should let Postgres itself determine the size of the database files. Deleted items are removed when a VACUUM operation is done; again, normally Postgres will do this via a regularly scheduled daemon. If you need to specifically recover space, then you can run VACUUM manually. See [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/routine-vacuuming.html).

Comment: So it's "ok" that space is not recovered after usage of `delete` method and that's everything about postgres? Almost 12 hours passed after deletion.